# Is $f(x,y) = x + y$ surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would like to know if the multivariable function $f(x,y) = x+y$ is surjective. I think I've figured out it is not injective as $g(2,3)$ and $g(5,0)$ both map to $5$, but I am not sure how to check for surjection on a multivariable function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $(\forall x\in\Bbb R):f(x,0)=x$.

Comment: Sorry sir, but I am still not sure what to do.

Comment: What else do you want? If $x\in\Bbb R$, then $x=f(x,0)$. Therefore, $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Oh okay thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You can use the definition. Take two real numbers $x_0$ and $c$. Now, pick $y_0=c-x_0$.